# Postgresql restrict pg_catalog and information schema (procedure source, table columns) is not working

Tags: postgresql, catalog

We are trying to restrict access to postgresql for development user.

The development user will be having access to a schema with views and rules.

However the user should not have any access to catalog, information schemas or revoked usage schemas, modifying/viewing table columns, viewing procedure source etc from pgadmin web portal or other db connections.

The user will be used to connect to db i.e. in backend (java/python) code for making crud calls to the views & rules.

I have tried below which are not working: -

```
    REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA pg_catalog FROM appuser;
    REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA information_schema FROM appuser;
    REVOKE USAGE ON SCHEMA pg_catalog FROM appuser;
    REVOKE USAGE ON SCHEMA information_schema FROM appuser;
    REVOKE ALL ON pg_catalog.pg_roles FROM appuser;
    REVOKE ALL ON pg_catalog.pg_proc FROM appuser;
```

Even after revoking these access, the user can view catalog and query from pg tables.

Furthermore, I have also revoked access from public.

```
    REVOKE ALL     ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;
    REVOKE ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC ;
    REVOKE ALL   ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;
    REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE postgres FROM PUBLIC;
```

There is no change in access inspite of revoking access frmo public.

Comment: Don't try to do that. It won't work, and it won't improve security. Use two different databases.

Comment: Thanks @LaurenzAlbe for quick inputs. Lets say I use 2 DBs - dbA & dbB. User ua has access to DBa & DBb, and user ub has access to DBb. How can ub call procedures defined in DBa, without having access to DBa? Can we somehow grant access to ub for DBa.proc or create a wrapper proc in DBb which can in turn call proc in DBa?

Comment: You cannot use a foreign data wrapper to call procedures in a different database. One tool that you could use for that is PL/Proxy, but that's additional software. Why does it bother you if user `ub` has access to the metadata of `dbA`?

Comment: This is our access design. We need to provide access to client users to DB, but not expose any proc/func code or anything else in core DB/schema. They can query views or execute proc/func (through a wrapper DB or schema), but not see the source code or db indexes/sequences or any other objects in core DB. We thought this would be possible somehow in Postgresql.

Comment: Not really. You should change your design.

Comment: Thanks @LaurenzAlbe for your inputs.

Comment: Following your comment on the referenced answer, "You would have to deny the user access to the pg_class, pg_namespace and pg_proc and similar tables. This can be done if you set allow_system_table_mods to on" ... I have enabled allow_system_table_mods to on and confirmed by show command. After restarting server, I have issued revoked commands from public and <concerned_user> for schemas pg_catalog & information_schema, and tables pg_roles, pg_proc, pg_class, pg_namespace. However, <concerned_user> can still query these in PGAdmin & see the stored procs. Any help on this?

Comment: That depends on what exactly you revoked and which user you use in pgAdmin. Superusers are exempt from permission checks. If in doubt, ask a new question for that.